# Why Frankie wants Chad's classroom look like dog pound?

Tags: plot-explanation, double-impact

In *Double Impact (1991)*, Chad is a Karate Master and aerobic guru, But Frankie
sending him to Hong Kong for business.

> Chad: Hong Kong? Uncle Frankie. Get real, man. We can't just cut out
>   for two weeks. We got a business  to run.
>
> Frankie: You have another business to run in Hong Kong.

Chad points his finger to Frankie's class room and said this words:

[image]

> Frankie: **Make this thing look like a fucking dog pound**.
>
> Chad: Another business in Hong Kong. Uncle Frankie...

Comment: That's not what is being said. [(Chad walks into Uncle Frankies office) Chad - Hong Kong? Uncle Frankie...We can't cut 2 weeks in Hong Kong...We got a business to run! (pointing whole left arm out the of the frame) Uncle Frankie - You've got another business in Hong Kong that'll make this thing look like a fucking dog pound!](http://www.moviequotes.com/repository.cgi?pg=3&tt=90264)

Comment: There is no **that'll** in the dialogue like you posted in comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Frank is trying to say is that whatever business Chad has in Los Angeles is minor (looks like a dog pound) **in comparison** to the business in Hong Kong.

> You have another business to run in Hong Kong *(that will)* Make this thing look
>   like a fucking dog pound.

In this case, he's omitted the joining phrase...that's all.